# how to enable Sql Command tracking in application insight using arm template

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-rm-template

We start to use Application insight to track our performance. 
I found some examples and manged to do these in my arm template:

```
           {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
              "value": "[reference(variables('appInsightsResourceID'), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
            },
            {
              "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~2"
            },
            {
              "name": "DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~3"
            },
            {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION",
              "value": "1.0.0"
            }
```

This seems enabled Profiler, disabled Snapshot debugger and has Collection level to be "Recommended".

However, if I want to enable Sql command tracking, what should I do? I wasn't able to find an example and if I export template, seems there is no setting related to application insight exported.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try setting these 2 properties along with your exiting ones?

```
"Properties": {
        "InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~1",
        "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions": "~1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ARM template with these settings just before you create the Web App by clicking on the **Download a template for automation**" option. You may later tweak the settings within as per your requirements. The following template and settings work for me, and include the properties that @bit pointed above:

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "subscriptionId": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "hostingEnvironment": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "hostingPlanName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "serverFarmResourceGroup": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "alwaysOn": {
        "type": "bool"
    },
    "currentStack": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "tags": {},
        "dependsOn": [],
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                    {
                        "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                        "value": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                        "value": "~2"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode",
                        "value": "recommended"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                        "value": "~3"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION",
                        "value": "1.0.0"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION",
                        "value": "disabled"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                        "value": "~1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "SnapshotDebugger_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                        "value": "disabled"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions",
                        "value": "~1"
                    }
                ],
                "metadata": [
                    {
                        "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                        "value": "[parameters('currentStack')]"
                    }
                ],
                "alwaysOn": "[parameters('alwaysOn')]"
            },
            "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
            "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('hostingEnvironment')]",
            "clientAffinityEnabled": true
        }
    }
]
```

}

Deploying this template gives me an App Service with the following configuration:

[image]

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps#application-settings-definitions) doc for reading about the Application settings definitions used above.

Hope this helps!